# How to fetch my gmail inbox with Meteor percolate:google-api?

Tags: javascript, meteor, gmail

I installed the package

```
meteor add percolate:google-api
```

and cofigured the accounts:ui and accounts-google and I am logged in with my gmail.

Not sure of where to put and what to do next to fetch all my gmail emails.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at the Google API to get this to work. Have a look here for example: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

Make a GET request for the messages in the users inbox using:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages
```

And you'd do that using the package by calling:

```
GoogleApi.get('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages', options[, callback]);
```

Comment: I am sorry man , I am a total noob , I added your code to a Meteor.method and then called it in the console to see if it fetches the email in the terminal but didn't....any chance you can point me in the right direction? thank you for your time....I was logged in with accounts-ui  and my gmail

Comment: You need to replace userId with the correct google userId. You'll need to read the docs to see how to do that. Just the console for errors too. Playing with this api might be too difficult for a noob. It's really just about sitting down and reading docs and trying it out